# Where can I find distribution circuit GIS datasets for amperage / voltage service at parcel or structure level?

Tags: data-request, energy

Does anyone know of free or public sources of parcel data with electrical service information, ie amperage and voltage? I want to make a custom web map for compliance / siting for energy-intensive uses. Not sure if this is usually private info held by utilities, or not available because amperage service is often determined by the main breaker installed inside a building. I've found a few from several energy companies like https://greenmountainpower.com/help/3-phase-service-vermont/ but nothing at parcel / building level. Ideally I would like a dataset with attribute fields for phase (looking for 3 phase), voltage and network endpoints.